# PHP Convert to int

Tags: php, integer, numbers, expand

Im not sure what this type of number is '1.3122278540256E+18' but how can i expand it into an integer?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a floating-point number expressed in scientific notation (the "E+18" means "times 10 to the 18th power"). Chances are it's being displayed that way due to its length; you might try using [printf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) to format it as a standard integer.

Answer (score 2):

It is in  [IEEE floating point notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). It is a number too large to be calcuated exactly, but move the decimal +18 places to the right to get the integer.

Answer (score 1):

This is scientific notation.

E+18 is shorthand for 10^18. In this case, the number you see is 1,312,227,854,025,600,000.